# Open Outlook Mail Window from a blazor webassembly application

Tags: c#, email, .net-core, outlook, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor Web assembly and I need to pop open a outlook compose mail window from an account on the client machine who is already logged in to outlook email. I am trying to use the Microsoft office outlook interop COM reference and it is not working, even on my local machine. This is the code I have in one of the razor.cs files:

```
  using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
  Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
  Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = 
  (Outlook._MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMailItem.GetInspector; 
            oMailItem.To = "test.test@test.com";
            oMailItem.CC = "test.test@test.com";
            oMailItem.Subject = "Testing Outlook Interop";
            oMailItem.Body = "Testing Outlook Interop";
            oMailItem.Display(true);
```

My questions are: Is it possible to go this route and how to do it? How is it able to access the account of the user who is logged into outlook once it is published on cloud? If this is not the right way, what is outlook interop even used for? I would like an excel sheet to be attached to the email, so as far as graph API goes, I am unable to attach excel. Please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you get any error messages or exception in the code? Could you be more specific?

Comment: In the catch block I get a system exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type').                                                                                                This reference the line [Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();]

Comment: I think a local Outlook install would be required, so in the cloud this would fail.
If you want to use your mail server from the cloud you'll need to use SMTP.

You could try adding a link in HTML and pointing the href to 'mailto:' and then the email address you want to send mail to. You can then add the cc, subject and body using query string properties. 

Eg: <a href="mailto:test.test@test.com?cc=test.test@test.com&subject=Testing&bodt=Body-goes-here">Email Us</a>

This will open the user's default mail client on their local machine, using their existing account.

Comment: Using mailto its difficult to add attachments, I've read that its not a good way to go, if you have attachments?

Answer (score 0):

> In the catch block I get a system exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type'). This reference the line [Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();]

Outlook must be installed on the system. Most probably your code is executed isolated and cannot locate the COM server which should be automated on the end user machine.

Instead, you may consider using the [mailto protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) which opens a client's e-mail system and begins a new email message. For example, on the web page you may use the following HTML markup:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?
    subject=MessageTitle&amp;
    body=Message Content">
    Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: I am on my work machine where I am actively logged in to outlook. And the code is running on localhost thru VS IISExpress. . Is there a way to attach file using mailto?

Comment: See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2)